# Display Sql results based on Percentages

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

Good Day Guys! I am trying to get a desired result in SQL.

I have a Table like this

```
Products | Colors
******************
Bag      | Blue
Shoes    | Blue
Shirt    | Yellow
Sandal   | Yellow
Phone    | Yellow
Cotton   | Blue
Paper    | Blue
Biro     | Blue
Track    | Yellow
Pouch    | Yellow
Cap      | Yellow
Hat      | Yellow
Pants    | Blue
Bucket   | Blue
Belt     | Blue
Car      | Yellow
Socks    | Yellow
```

The rows above is 20.

What I want to achieve is to display 10 results at random:

where:
3 rows (30% of the result) are blue and
7 rows (70% of the result) are yellow.

Thank you. I apologize for not asking with details.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: To ask an On Topic question, please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)
 **We are very willing to help you fix your code, but we dont write code for you**

Comment: I have no idea on what to try that was why i asked

Comment: can you filter the rows in frontend instead of in SQL?

Comment: Start by looking up COUNT() in the SQL manual

Comment: Edit your question and show the result set.  Explain what happens when you don't have enough rows to meet the conditions.  Also, you need to explain how many rows you want.  Are you duplicating rows to get to the percentages?  The question is very ambiguous, incomplete.

Comment: But which 30%??

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have enough rows. And what i want is a result of 10 rows each time the query runs. I have over a hundred rows

Comment: @Strawberry Products with Blue Color are 30%

Comment: @pro_cheats I can't really do that. because its like a question of different categories. Entertainment and Sport. That Kinda thing.

Comment: Yes. But which ones.

Comment: @kelrob please explain with sample input and output, with 10 records.

Comment: 30% of blue from your example = bag, 70% of yellow = shirt,sandal? or do you mean give me 10 records 3 blue and 7 yellow? and you don't care which 3 or which 7.

Comment: You should google mysql select random rows. Use 2 selects and a union as well.

Comment: @pro_cheats I have reviewed the question . Please kindly check it out again.

Comment: @Strawberry thanks.

Comment: It is ok to be sorry for no details... But not ok to not give details,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a method that almost does what you want. To achieve your exact specification in pure SQL is quite a lot more involved...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(Products VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
,Colors VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(products,colors)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
('Bag','Blue'),
('Shoes','Blue'),
('Shirt','Yellow'),
('Sandal','Yellow'),
('Phone','Yellow'),
('Cotton','Blue'),
('Paper','Blue'),
('Biro','Blue'),
('Track','Yellow'),
('Pouch','Yellow'),
('Cap','Yellow'),
('Hat','Yellow'),
('Pants','Blue'),
('Bucket','Blue'),
('Belt','Blue'),
('Car','Yellow'),
('Socks','Yellow');

SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY CASE WHEN colors = 'blue' THEN RAND()*3 ELSE RAND()*7 END DESC LIMIT 10;
+----------+--------+
| Products | Colors |
+----------+--------+
| Socks    | Yellow |
| Shirt    | Yellow |
| Hat      | Yellow |
| Track    | Yellow |
| Cap      | Yellow |
| Sandal   | Yellow |
| Car      | Yellow |
| Pants    | Blue   |
| Shoes    | Blue   |
| Belt     | Blue   |
+----------+--------+

SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY CASE WHEN colors = 'blue' THEN RAND()*3 ELSE RAND()*7 END DESC LIMIT 10;
+----------+--------+
| Products | Colors |
+----------+--------+
| Track    | Yellow |
| Phone    | Yellow |
| Hat      | Yellow |
| Socks    | Yellow |
| Cap      | Yellow |
| Sandal   | Yellow |
| Shoes    | Blue   |
| Biro     | Blue   |
| Pouch    | Yellow |
| Bucket   | Blue   |
+----------+--------+

SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY CASE WHEN colors = 'blue' THEN RAND()*3 ELSE RAND()*7 END DESC LIMIT 10;
+----------+--------+
| Products | Colors |
+----------+--------+
| Sandal   | Yellow |
| Hat      | Yellow |
| Pouch    | Yellow |
| Socks    | Yellow |
| Cap      | Yellow |
| Bucket   | Blue   |
| Paper    | Blue   |
| Phone    | Yellow |
| Track    | Yellow |
| Shirt    | Yellow |
+----------+--------+
```

Comment: Awesome!!Really nice and exactly what i want @Strawberry. But I noticed at times it brings out just 1 blue row. and 9 Yellow rows. Any Reason its fluctuating?

Comment: Yes. As per my introduction. This is a weighted probability. It's possible (although unlikely) to return all 8 blue entries using this method.

Comment: @kelrob . . . This is indeed an interesting and clever solution for getting an *approximate* 30%/70% split.  It is surprising that you accepted it, given that it does not appear to meet your actual requirement.